# Objects not freed after web-request

Tags: java, spring

I have encountered some weird problem/behavior Spring ResetController requests if I can call them like that.
As I am not that familiar with Spring, maybe it is normal, I am just surprised, that after receiving some POST requests, objects I have created during a call is not being removed from memory.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/run2")
public String api2() {

    try {
        new ServerSocket(8887);
        return "run2";
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return "run2nok";
    }
}
```

With my understanding, each time I would call `new ServerSocket(8887)` I would be able to bind to a port, only if it's not being used. And as far as I can tell by this shortcode, its life-cycle should end after a return.

But when I make second POST call, its cant bind to a port, and by checking in CMD `netstat | findstr: 8887` it is being used.
But if I call `System.gc()` then the port is being freed, and I can make 2nd POST, like I need to.

So, does its normal, that object is still in use after the request has ended, or do I need to do something to free port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never rely upon something being cleaned up automatically in a timely fashion - it may happen immediately, later, or never (it is not even guaranteed to happen in response to `System.gc()`).

If you need cleanup, do it explicitly (e.g. via a finally, or using try-with-resources).

Comment: Totally had it out of my mind, that i should try to assign it to variable and then close it. Thanks for pointing that out to me. I had my mind out of place, since it was working fine in plain java, but when i run this on Spring, it wasn't.